# Font rendering problems using Pango + Cairo + Fontconfig using Visual Studio, under GCC works fine

Tags: visual-studio, mingw, cairo, pango

I have a big problem, and I hope you can help me.

I'm porting a game from Linux to Windows, and using MinGW works fine (except for some crashes that I don't know how, but this is not my problem now)

Game use Fontconfig (2.4.2-3), Cairo (1.8.8) and Pango (1.26.0) to render text.

Problem is that, using Visual Studio, I can't see fonts (all characters are displayed as little box), and in the output it say me this:

```
** (performous.exe:4344): CRITICAL **: No modules found:
No builtin or dynamically loaded modules were found.
PangoFc will not work correctly.
This probably means there was an error in the creation of:
  'D:\Project\PerformousInstall-vc\etc\pango\pango.modules'
You should create this file by running:
  pango-querymodules > 'D:\Project\PerformousInstall-vc\etc\pango\pango.modules'


** (performous.exe:4344): WARNING **: couldn't load font "Bitstream Charter Not-Rotated 18px", falling back to "Sans Not-Rotated 18px", expect ugly output.

** (performous.exe:4344): WARNING **: couldn't load font "Sans Not-Rotated 18px", falling back to "Sans Not-Rotated 18px", expect ugly output.

** (performous.exe:4344): WARNING **: All font fallbacks failed!!!!

** (performous.exe:4344): WARNING **: failed to choose a font, expect ugly output. engine-type='PangoRenderWin32', script='latin'

** (performous.exe:4344): WARNING **: All font fallbacks failed!!!!
```

This error is only when I use Visual Studio, but because it fix me a lot of other bugs, I'll be very interested to get fonts working under VS.

Sorry if I forgot something or I haven't posted anything, but I have no idea what to post.

Someone has some hints?

Thanks in advance for help, if I don't get myself clear, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the fonts that Pango are using to something that actually exists on a Windows machine, neither Bitstream nor Sans exist and that's what Pango is telling you (its default is Sans). Try setting it to Segoe UI and you should see text

Comment: Thanks for reply, I tried to do that, now I have "only" this error:


  ** (performous.exe:4344): WARNING **: failed to choose a font, expect ugly output. engine-type='PangoRenderWin32', script='latin'

Don't know how to solve it. Maybe 


PS: tried with "Arial" and "Verdana" too, no effective. What about modules error? I can't find anything usefully on Google

Comment: Go into the pango room on GNOME IRC "#pango" or on the mailing list, the people there are really helpful and friendly

Comment: Ok, problem solved: copy generated "module-*" of a compiled pango under MinGW into directory of pango of Visual C++, inverted second line with four of every group, compile and all works. If someone has trouble, feel free to contact me. Thanks Paul for the answer